# Integrate $\frac{x^2-4x+10}{x^2\sqrt x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

> Find the indefinate integral with respect to $x$ of $$\frac{x^2-4x+10}{x^2\sqrt x}$$

For this problem I first made each individual number in the numerator separate from each other for easier integration and then simplified

$$=\int \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2\sqrt x}-\frac{4x}{x^2\sqrt x}+\frac{10}{x^2\sqrt x}\right)dx$$
$$=\int \left(x^2x^{-\frac{3}{2}}-4x^1x^{-\frac{3}{2}}+10x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)dx$$
$$=\int \left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4x^{-\frac{1}{2}}+10x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)dx$$

I then integrated the expression to get

$$\frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}-8x^{\frac{1}{2}}-20x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

This is, however, wrong. Any ideas as to why?

Thanks in advance $:)$

Comment: Note that $x^2\sqrt{x}=x^{2+\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{5}{2}}$.

Comment: The powers in the integrand are $-1/2,-3/2,-5/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2-4x+10}{x^2\sqrt x}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{4}{x\sqrt{x}}+\frac{10}{x^2\sqrt{x}}$$
$$x^{-1/2}-4x^{-3/2}+10x^{-5/2}$$

So it should be  $x^{-5/2}$ instead of $x^{-3/2}$

$$I=\int x^{-1/2}-4x^{-3/2}+10x^{-5/2} {dx}=2x^{1/2}+8x^{-1/2}-\frac{20}{3}x^{-3/2}+C$$

Answer (score 4):

Check again it should be

$$=\int \left(x^{-\frac{1}{2}}-4x^{-\frac{3}{2}}+10x^{-\frac{5}{2}}\right)dx$$

indeed $\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt x}=x^{-\frac{5}{2}}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is $x^{-5/2}$ and not $x^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Place $t=\sqrt{x}$, after you solve the integral of a rational function.

Comment: A little overkill, integrating a half-integer power isn't more difficult than an integer one.

Answer (score 1):

You could have noticed that the $x^2$ simplify in the first term,

$$\frac{x^2+\cdots}{x^2\sqrt x}=\frac1{\sqrt x}+\cdots=x^{-1/2}+\cdots$$

So with a little more care,

$$\int(x^{-1/2}-4x^{-3/2}+10x^{-5/2})\,dx=\frac21x^{1/2}-\frac21(-4)x^{-1/2}-\frac2310x^{-3/2}.$$

Comment: Disappointing downvotes. I am giving the OP a hint to understand/avoid his mistake.